# How do I show $(a+b)^K=\sum _{n=0}^K \binom{K}{n} b^n a^{K-n} $ without using recurrence?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, research

We already know that we can represent this binomial as the following:

$$(a+b)^K=\sum _{n=0}^K \binom{K}{n} b^n a^{K-n};$$

where $\binom{K}{n} = \frac{K!}{n! (K-n)!}$

**My question here is**  :How do I show this :$(a+b)^K=\sum _{n=0}^K \binom{K}{n} b^n a^{K-n};  $ is true without using recurrence demonstration?

**Note**: I know only recurrence method.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 3):

**Calculus proof**:

It suffices to show it's true for $(1+x)^K$ since you can factor out $a$ and let $x=b/a$. Then

\begin{align*}
[x^n](1+x)^K&=\frac{1}{n!}\left.\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(1+x)^K\right|_{x=0}\\
&=\frac{1}{n!}K(K-1)\cdots (K-n+1)=\binom{K}{n}.
\end{align*}

So the coefficient infront of $x^n$ is $\binom{K}{n}$. Thus:

$$(a+b)^K=a^K(1+b/a)^K=a^K\sum_{n=0}^K\binom{K}{n}(b/a)^n=\sum_{n=0}^K\binom{K}{n}b^na^{K-n}.$$

Note that the sum has to start from $n=0$ since that's the lowest power of $x$ and also terminates at $n=K$ because that's the highest power (and also the binomial coefficient vanishes).

**Combinatorics proof**:

The coefficient $a^nb^{N-k}$ occurs as my times as one can pick sequences of length $K$ with exactly $n$ $a$'s (without regard to order) and $n-K$ $b$'s. from the set $\{a,b\}^K$. Equivalently, you are picking $n$ team members from a team of size $K$ with to form team $a$, the remaining ones form team $b$.  This is exactly $\binom{K}{n}=\binom{K}{K-n}$.

Comment: thank you , i think this is the only way to prove  but i see in your answer which you are used reccurence relation and the last should be prove by reccurence way

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: where is there a recurrence relation being used? Just so we're on the same page, a recurrence is something like $a_n=a_{n-1}+2$, or similar right?

Comment: I know but to prove if it's true also should for you using reccurence way

Comment: @zeraouliarafik: just to clarify. In your question you're asking for a proof that doesn't involve recurrence, but now you're saying you want a recurrence proof?

Comment: This :\begin{align*}
[x^n](1+x)^K&=\frac{1}{n!}\left.\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(1+x)^K\right|_{x=0}\\
&=\frac{1}{n!}K(K-1)\cdots (K-n+1)=\binom{K}{n}.
\end{align*} what i meant

Comment: no, i don't need a reccurence proof

Answer (score 0):

Really, $(a+b)^K=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^K\dbinom{K}na^n b^{K-n}$ is the *definition* of the binomial coefficients.

Then considering the equality $\bigl((1+x)^K\bigr)'=K(1+x)^{K-1},\enspace K\ge 1$, and the developments of both sides, you can establish the relation:
$$\binom Kn=\frac Kn\binom{K-1}{n-1},$$ 
from which you deduce by a trivial induction (or with a telescoping product):
$$\binom Kn=\frac{K(K-1)\dots(K-n+1)}{n!}=\frac{K!}{n!\,(K-n)!}$$

Comment: Definition might be a strong word. The binomial theorem can be proven axiomatically, and the binomial coefficient has a combinatorial proof as well as an algebraic proof regarding quotients of symmetry groups.

Comment: @ml0105: That's the way I learnt it. In this approach,the ‘combinatorial proof’  is  the theorem that $\;C_K^n=\dbinom Kn$. In my opinion, it's the simplest, conceptually.